# Get a document by LUUID

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I got an .net core application that is pretty straight forward it is using REST to add and download objects to and from mongo db. Adding items works really well. Getting a list that contains all items aswell, but when I try to access one using `id` then everytime I get `null`. **What should i change to make this piece of code work. It means get a Tool object from database using it unique ID when there's one matching in database.**

**Here's a object in database**
[image: database view]
**Here's my repository class**

```
private IMongoCollection<Tool> Tools => _database.GetCollection<Tool>("Tools");

    public async Task<Tool> GetAsync(Guid id) =>
            await Tools.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefaultAsync(tool => tool.Id == id);
```

Argument looks like that when I check it out in debugger `"{ee1aa9fa-5d17-464c-a8ba-f685203b911f}"`

***Edit***

**Tool Class Properties**

```
public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

public string Model { get; protected set; }

public string Brand { get; protected set; }

public string Type { get; protected set; }

public uint Box { get; protected set; }
```

**Fixed check comments**

[Project on github](https://github.com/kwiniarski97/Tools-in-Garage)

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I though it explains itself, but added

Comment: Nope, still no idea what your asking?

Comment: Why this doesn't work? Where's the error?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in C# MongoDB Driver is to set a global `GuidRepresentation` setting which can be found on the `BsonDefaults` object. This is a global setting and will effect all serialization/deserialization of GUIDs in to Bson Binary Objects.

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.PythonLegacy;

var collection =  new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<ClassA>("test");

var item = collection.Find(x => x.MyId == new Guid("ee1aa9fa-5d17-464c-a8ba-f685203b911f"))
.FirstOrDefault();
```

The second option is to convert the GUID manually from a LUUID to a CSUUID, for this there is a helper class within the MongoDB driver of `GuidConverter`, with this it converts the `GUID` in to `byte[]` which is normally used for storage but we can use it for our query.

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy;

var collection =  new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<ClassA>("test");

var luuid = new Guid("0798f048-d8bb-7048-bb92-7518ea4272cb");
var bytes = GuidConverter.ToBytes(luuid, GuidRepresentation.PythonLegacy);
var csuuid = new Guid(bytes);

var item = collection.Find(x => x.MyId == csuuid)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I also noticed that you're using Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo), within this application you can set how GUIDs are displayed by going to `Options` -> `Legacy UUID Encodings`

[image: RoboMongo]

Comment: I wish i could upvote you. I tried both solutions and both of them are working. Many many thanks for great answer!

Comment: This is the first working solution I've found in 2018. Many thanks!